# Iterate through rows of numpy array to find mode

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to create a decision tree classifier function that will build an ensemble of decision trees and make the final prediction based on the majority vote prediction from all the trees. My approach is to build a matrix that has each decision tree's prediction in a separate column, and then for every row (corresponding to each data point), finding the modal value to make the final prediction for that data point.

So far my function is:

```
def majority_classify(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, num_samples):

n = x_train.shape[0]
c=len(np.unique(y_train))

votes=np.zeros((n, c))
predictions_train=np.empty((n, num_samples+1))
predictions_test=np.empty((n, num_samples))


for i in range(0, num_samples):
    # Randomly a sample points from the train set of size 'n'
    indices = np.random.choice(np.arange(0, n), size=n)

    x_train_sample = x_train[indices, :]
    y_train_sample = y_train[indices]

    dt_major = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth = 2)
    model_major = dt_major.fit(x_train, y_train)

    predictions_train[:,i]=model_major.predict(x_train)




for r in predictions_train:
    predict_train = mode(r)[0][0]
```

However, what I'm having trouble with is figuring how to iterate through each row and find the mode. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html) is a good place to start. You should include a **minimal** example of the input, and the desired result in your question.

Comment: I'd like to iterate over each row as a single unit, not iterate over the items within each row. I don't think I'm seeing how to do that in that documentation.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/quickstart.html#indexing-slicing-and-iterating

Comment: Can you use any package or are you restricted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- use `np.unique` with the `return_counts` parameter.
- use the `argmax` on the counts array to get value from unique array.
- use `np.apply_along_axis` for a custom function `mode`

---

```
def mode(a):
    u, c = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
    return u[c.argmax()]

a = np.array([
        [1, 2, 3],
        [2, 3, 4],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [2, 5, 6],
        [4, 1, 7],
        [5, 4, 8],
        [6, 6, 3]
    ])

np.apply_along_axis(mode, 0, a)

array([2, 4, 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out `scipy.stats.mode`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import mode

>>> a = np.array([[1,1,0],[1,2,2],[2,0,0]])
>>> mode(a, axis=1)[0]
array([[1],
       [2],
       [0]])
```